# Proper way of calling Activity Method from recycler adapther in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need to call an Intent from the `onBindViewHolder` of the `recycler` adapter , on a click event from one of the views in the `ViewHolder`. I am unable to do so directly ..

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.button.setonClickListener(new View.onClickListener(
               @Override
               onClick(View v) {
               Intent i=new Intent();
                i.setAction("Intent.ACTION_CALL");
                i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        ));
}
```

This did not work. It kept throwing error. I then created a public method in the Activity with the same code. Passed Activity context in the Adapter constructor. Then called the Method as follows from button click event.

```
((MyActivity)context).makePhoneCall("1234567890");
```

This did the trick. But i feel there should be a better method of doing this.
As i am primarily from C background, i am not sure.
So my question is there a better or more proper way to do this , according to Java programming conventions.

Comment: Basically `startActivity()` method is from `Activity` class. So, we need to handle like that only.

Comment: @NigamPatro `startActivity()` method is from `Context` class.

Comment: @fRoStBiT yup buddy, sorry, its from `Context` class and you are right.

Comment: Please, Post your activity. Just tell me what you want exactly solution of your posted code or you want information about best way to startActivity

Comment: @Ajinkya what i want is , to know what is the best way to access a Method defined in an Activity from the Recycler Adapter.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call another activity via Intent, you can use any view's `Context`:

```
v.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

I think this is a correct method.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to implement a listener in the recycleradapter and listen it in the activity.

So in the adapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter .... {    

    private MyClickListener listener;


    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.button.setonClickListener(new View.onClickListener(
               @Override
               onClick(View v) {
                  listener.onClicked(true);
            }
        ));

    public void setMyClickListener(MyClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

}
```

//create MyClickListener.class

```
public interface MyClickListener {

               public void onClicked(boolean status);
        }
```

In your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity ... implements MyClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


adapter.setMyClickListener(this);

}

@Override
onClick(boolean status) {
      if (status){
            Intent i=new Intent();
            i.setAction("Intent.ACTION_CALL");
            i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"));
            startActivity(i);
      };
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
In your Adapter:

```
 Activity mContext;

public FollowersAdapter(Activity mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}
```

//And then your click in onBindViewHolder

```
  holder.linear_user.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("linear click>>>>>>>>>>>>");

            Intent ToImage = new Intent(mContext, UserData.class);
            ToImage.putExtra("user_id", data.get(position).getFollower_id());
            mContext.startActivity(ToImage);

        }
    });
```

Comment: this the method i am currently using. I wanted to know if this is the proper way or if there is a more proper way to implement this.

Comment: Well I am using this way to call my activity and it is working fine for me, If  you find any other better way please let me know.